# I can't use value inside my UICollectionView from API ( Swift, MVVM, UIKit)

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, uicollectionview, combine

I'm trying to make simple app that shows a list with values from API. The thing is that I can't use that same way like previous projects. I got a error message:

```
failure(Swift.DecodingError.typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil)))
```

This is my code:

1. ViewController

```
import UIKit
import Combine

class PokedexViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    private var pokedexListVM = PokedexListViewModel()
    
    var collectionView: UICollectionView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        setupCollectionView()
        
    }
    
    private func setupCollectionView() {
        
        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 0, right: 5)
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: view.bounds.size.width, height: 60)
        
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView?.register(PokedexCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: PokedexCollectionViewCell.identifier)
        
        collectionView?.delegate = self
        collectionView?.dataSource = self
        
        view.addSubview(collectionView ?? UICollectionView())
        //self.view = view
        setupViewModel()
        
    }
    
    private func setupViewModel() {
        
        pokedexListVM.$pokemons
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .sink(receiveValue: { [weak self] _ in
                self?.collectionView!.reloadData()
            }).store(in: &subscriptions)
        
        let stateHandler: (PokedexListViewModelState) -> Void = { state in
            switch state {
            case .loading:
                print("loading")
            case .finishLoading:
                print("finish")
            case .error:
                print("error")
            }
        }
        
        pokedexListVM.$state
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .sink(receiveValue: stateHandler)
            .store(in: &subscriptions)
        
    }
    
}

extension PokedexViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return pokedexListVM.pokemons.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
         guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(
            withReuseIdentifier: PokedexCollectionViewCell.identifier,
            for: indexPath
         ) as? PokedexCollectionViewCell else {
            return UICollectionViewCell()
        }
        
        cell.configure(with: "\(pokedexListVM.pokemons[indexPath.row].name)")
        
        return cell
    }
    
}
```

2. ViewModel

```
    import Foundation
import Combine

enum PokedexListViewModelState {
    case loading
    case finishLoading
    case error
}

class PokedexListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published private(set) var pokemons: [Pokedex.Results] = []
    @Published private(set) var state: PokedexListViewModelState = .loading
    private var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    private var url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=0&limit=898"
    //private let url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/"
    
    init() {
        loadPokemons()
    }
    
    private func loadPokemons() {
        
        state = .loading
        
        let valueHandler: ([Pokedex.Results]) -> Void = { [weak self] items in
            self?.pokemons = items
        }
        
        let completionHandler: (Subscribers.Completion<Error>) -> Void = { [weak self] completion in
            switch completion {
            case .failure:
                self?.state = .error
                print(completion)
            case .finished:
                self?.state = .finishLoading
            }
        }
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: URL(string: url)!)
            .map{ $0.data }
            .decode(type: [Pokedex.Results].self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .sink(receiveCompletion: completionHandler, receiveValue: valueHandler)
            .store(in: &subscriptions)
        
    }
}
```

3. Model

```
import Foundation

struct Pokedex: Codable {
    
    struct Results: Codable {
        let name: String
        let url: String
    }

    var results: [Results]
    var count: Int
    var next: String
    var previous: String?
    
}
```

I use pokeAPIV2 from that link:
https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=0&limit=898

```
{
"count": 1154,
"next": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=3&limit=3",
"previous": null,
"results": [
{
"name": "bulbasaur",
"url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/"
},
{
"name": "ivysaur",
"url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/2/"
},
{
"name": "venusaur",
"url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/3/"
}
]
}
```

I want to use the "name" data from that API.
One thing that I noticed is that API starts from "{" and previous ones starts from "[".

Comment: You should decode `Pokedex.self` and not `.decode(type: [Pokedex.Results].self, decoder: JSONDecoder())`

Comment: Hi @FabioFelici. Can u explain that on my ViewModel? I don't catch that because when I simply changed the following code there is a lot of errors. Additional question. Is my Model typed correctly? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model should be like this:

```
import Foundation

struct Pokedex: Codable {
    var results: [Results]
    var count: Int
    var next: String
    var previous: String?
}

struct Results: Codable {
        let name: String
        let url: String
    }
```

And your View Model should be like this:

```
URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: URL(string: url)!)
            .map{ $0.data }
            **.decode(type: Pokedex.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())**
            .sink(receiveCompletion: completionHandler, receiveValue: valueHandler)
            .store(in: &subscriptions)
```

Comment: Ok @Chetan got it but right now i got an error in ``` init() { self.loadPokemons() } ```. Where is the problem tight now? Another thing, how can I call name properity inside my **PokedexCollectionView** ? Right now i can call only whole **Result** struct.

Comment: is your first problem solved? Now change your pokemons array and valueHandler type from [Pokedex.Results] to [Results] in ViewModel class.

Comment: Not at all. I got that type of error when i tried your solution: **Cannot convert value of type '([Results]) -> Void' to expected argument type '(Pokedex) -> Void'**. It's all in the **sink()** when I calling **valueHandler**